# Hibernate and dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, dynamic

do you know anything about Hibernate and its ability to generate dynamic sql queries with HQL?

I you have any links I would appreciate posting, I can't find nothing about it in Hibernate`s documentation.

Best regards
Gabe

//edit
so maybe I will precise what I mean. I am wondering if some HQL code generates SQL queries which uses something like EXECUTE (for postgres)

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean. Why do you need execute statements? What's your *real* problem to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're aiming for here? HQL in Hibernate will always generate SQL, and you can put your HQL together differently based on input. It will always generate new SQL for each permutation and run. You can make Hibernate precompile/cache queries but that's just a performance optimization and shouldn't be your first concern.

I would also consider looking into the Criteria API which lets you stay a lot more object oriented instead of working with tons of strings.

Comment: I would like hibernate to produce an EXECUTE SQL statement

Comment: I don't agree with criteria being "a lot more object oriented". HQL is very object oriented, although it is another language stored in strings within java or xml. Criteria is less powerful. It is recommended for dynamic queries (instead of string manipulation to put HQL together).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about static queries using dynamic arguments, the syntax is

```
select f from Foo f where f.bar = ? and f.zim = ?
```

or, with named parameters

```
select f from Foo f where f.bar = :bar and f.zim = :zim
```

If you're talking about completely dynamically created queries based on a set of criteria, then the API to use is... the Criteria API.

Both are largely covered in the Hibernate reference documentation.

Comment: I would like hibernate to produce an EXECUTE SQL statement